# CMS for multiple community organizations under single domain

Tags: cms, .net

The premise: a single domain for a bunch of non-profit organizations in a community (say the Lions Club, local churches, the food bank, etc.). Each organization would have its own page on the site, with its own login that only allows them to edit their organization's page. An admin-level user would have global access to edit all pages, manage logins, etc.

- It must be super user friendly for non-technical users to login and
  maintain their page.
- Something .NET based would be preferable, as that's the tech I'm familiar with. Open to other platforms if needed.
- Free and open source preferred.

Comment: Each organization just has a single *page* (like a "business-card") – or rather a "set of pages"? What features should be available from the CMS end for each "user" (i.e. organization; e.g. WYSIWYG editor, image/file upload, template selection)?

Comment: For our purposes, we're thinking a single page per organization. They will mostly post contact info and upcoming events. A WYSIWYG editor would be nice. And a shared calendar that any logged in user could post events to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it does not match your desired criterion of being .NET-based, I highly recommend running [**WordPress**](http://wordpress.org/) in "[**multisite**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)" mode:

- Each organization in the community would get its own site (in the "network" of sites), with its own admin for that site.  (The individual sites can live in either subdomains or subdirectories relative to the root-domain.)
- The "super-admin" for the entire "network" has admin privileges for all of the organizational sites of the community.
- In addition to being very powerful, flexible, and extensible, WordPress is considered to be relatively user-friendly, out-of-the-box, as well.  But there are quite a few plugins (such as '[Adminize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/)') that allow the super-admin to simplify the admin dashboard even further, in a centralized manner, for all of the sites.
- The WordPress.org core, together with all of the numerous plugins featured in the official [Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/), are all [open-source, under the GPLv2 license](https://wordpress.org/about/license/).

Also, although you did not mention this as a requirement, WordPress gives you the option, via the [BuddyPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/buddypress/) plugin, to create a Facebook-like social-network, where each of the organization members can have their own personal profile and socially interact with other members.

Likewise, there are numerous calendar-related plugins that organizations could use to publicize upcoming events.